# Which ORM should I use for Node.js and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, orm, node.js

I'm rewriting a project to use Node.js. I'd like to keep using MySQL as the DB (even though I don't mind rewriting the schema).
I'm looking for a simple-to-use, reasonable-performance ORM, which supports caching, many-to-one and many-to-many relations.
From the MySQL ORMs I could find, [persistencejs](https://github.com/coresmart/persistencejs) and [sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) seem the most mature. 
Do you have experience with either? What are the relevant pros and cons I should be aware of in my decision?

Comment: But it's a very interesting theme. Would you like to get an access to third-party developers to change data on your site? May be it's better idea to create intermediate js library that sends request parameters (meta language) to a backend?

Comment: @sergzach Care to elaborate? Google for "hibernate caching".

Comment: Hm... Some sites allow user applications. Or I didn't understand you, excuse me please.

Comment: @sergzach: Caching is actually a fairly major feature of a number of ORM solutions. Look at Cayenne, for example.

Comment: Try [Oreo](https://github.com/will123195/oreo).  https://github.com/will123195/oreo

Comment: There is also [Bookshel.js](http://bookshelfjs.org/).

Comment: I developed this ORM that caches the whole database in memory. You can access data in a syncronous way, and control all the modifications with transactions. https://github.com/jbaylina/syncorm

Comment: ...and closed by someone who knows neither Node.js nor MySQL :-/ (just to get a bounty ?)

Comment: "closed as not constructive by Kev" ?!
seriously?... pardon my sarcasm.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

May I suggest Node ORM?

https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2

There's documentation on the Readme, supports MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite.

MongoDB is available since version **2.1.x** (released in July 2013)

UPDATE: This package is no longer maintained, per the project's README. It instead recommends [bookshelf](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf) and [sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize)

Comment: Based on the docs it looks like Sequelize is way ahead of this project.

Comment: It's another great option for people looking for mysql ORM. The syntax is more complex, but nice too.

Comment: the project has changed URL: https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2

Comment: I get this error "Error: Cannot find module 'hat'" when I try to deploy this.  .. no amount of npm install or re-install seems to help.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: hat is a dependency of the module and is stated in package.json. Are you sure there's nothing else conflicting with the instalation?

Comment: MongoDB is not an ORM.

Comment: MongoDB "is supported" by the ORM in question..

Comment: FYI: Sequelize doesn't support prepared statements.

Comment: Node-orm2 is no longer actively maintained. It links to sequelize and bookshelf.js.

Answer (score 161):

I would choose [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/) because of it's excellent documentation. It's just a honest opinion (I never really used MySQL with Node that much).

Comment: I would also like to point out that node-orm2 or persistence.js do not provide a migrations mechanism. persistence.js does not support postgres. sequelize does both of these things.

Comment: node-orm2 as of recently [has migrations](https://github.com/locomote/node-migrate-orm2)

Comment: I used node-orm2 and due to Sequelize's better documentation I was able to get it up and running much easier

Comment: Sequelize is no longer in development.

Comment: @Gelidus Where did you get this information?

Comment: @WilliamLepinski well, when I was installing it via npm, it told me so. But now I can see there is new commit 3 days ago. Sorry for that. :)

Comment: Np, @Gelidus. I was worried because I'm using it on a project.

Comment: Sadly, the Sequelize documentation has recently become terrible.  I started using Sequelize recently and was quite pleased by the docs.  Now it's an auto-generated pile of broken links, outdated information, and incomplete examples.  I'll still stick with it though.  It isn't that hard to learn.

Comment: hi all, what is your opinion on bookselfjs.org ?

Comment: Just deleted my old comment and I now 100% agree with @Brad , unfortunately :(

Comment: Sequelize - documentation and support is great but you're tied in with their chosen promise library and there's no support for prepared statements.

Comment: *I never really used MySQL with Node that much*. What do you prefer instead?

Comment: @Green MongoDB for fast prototyping, PostgreSql / Sqlite / LevelDB for the rest.

Comment: Sequelize does not have db automatic sync mechanism !

Comment: I just struggled with sequelize for many hours and I'm completely frustrated. There's no way to specify characters sets and collations on a per-column basis (only per-table or per-db defaults). This is a huge show stopper for me have serious doubts about this piece of software.

Comment: Don't use sequelize,... thats all I can say

Comment: Disagree. Sequelize docs is poor. Impossible to find a decent example of updating relationships (upsert). Objection has a proper documentation, similar to React-router v4. I moved out of Sequelize to ObjectionJs and I am happy with it!

Comment: I too feel like Sequelize documentation has gone downhill. They don't know whether they want you to use Sync() or manual migrations, and the documentation seems to waffle between the two. I was led down the Sync() path by an express sample project, only to later find out that Sync() is mainly a "development tool" and should not be used for production. If that is the case then remove it from the docs and all of the samples please. This is just one example of sequelize not having its stuff together. Imagine a whole ORM and docs full of this type of discrepancy.

Answer (score 19):

First off, please note that I haven't used either of them (but have used Node.js).

Both libraries are documented quite well and have a
stable API. However, persistence.js seems to be [used in more projects](http://persistencejs.org/users). I don't know if all of them still use it, though.

The developer of sequelize sometimes blogs about it at [blog.depold.com](http://blog.depold.com). When you'd like to use primary keys as foreign keys, you'll need the patch that's described in [this blog post](http://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2011/11/18/primary-key-foreign-key-improvements-to-sequelize-date-js-alternatives/). If you'd like help for persistence.js there is a google group devoted to it.

From the examples I gather that sequelize is a bit more JavaScript-like (more sugar) than persistance.js but has support for fewer datastores (only MySQL, while persistance.js can even use in-browser stores).

I think that sequelize might be the way to go for you, as you only need MySQL support. However, if you need some convenient features (for instance search) or want to use a different database later on you'd need to use persistence.js.

Comment: seems like http://persistencejs.org is now pointing to some unwanted site, only GitHub is working

Answer (score 11):

One major difference between Sequelize and Persistence.js is that the former supports a `STRING` datatype, i.e. `VARCHAR(255)`. I felt really uncomfortable making everything `TEXT`.

Comment: Currently Persistence.js supprts VARCHAR too.

Comment: In databases like PostgreSQL, TEXT and VARCHAR are exactly the same, the only difference is that if you put a byte limit (VARCHAR(255)) then you have an overhead for checking the limit. There is absolutely no issue in using TEXT for everything in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Using TEXT in PostgreSQL is actually the better practice, even if it's not portable.