# Using existing mysql schema in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

I tried using sequelize and node-orm as well - but is there a way to reuse existing mysql schema? I Have a db schema defined with tables in mysql and wanted to use this with my node.js app (using express).  So, I don't have to write all the define methods of defining tables again.
Any help appreciated...
I went through bunch of stackoverflow questions already such as: [Which ORM should I use for Node.js and MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007353/which-orm-should-i-use-for-node-js-and-mysql)

Thanks,
JP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [bookshelf.js](http://bookshelfjs.org), it doesn't require that you define the schema in the model layer.

Comment: Great library. But is it possible there to query specific columns? Select col1, col2, col3 from table where id >=1

Comment: model.query({column: ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], where: {id: 1}}).fetch() - it's just a thin relational model layer over http://knexjs.org