# Using PassportJS LocalStrategy in Node.js and trying to create a User object

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

Inside the `LocalStrategy` function I am trying to create a new user that I can pass-back with:

```
var newUser = new User();
```

and I am getting this error

> ```
> TypeError:  object is not a function
> ```

I can't seem to find the what has the definition for `User()`

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to define User Schema and import it using **require**

Answer (score 1):

passport has no definition for `User`, *per se*. It sounds to me as if you might want to make use of a schema or similar kind of model.

For example, if your back-end is based on MongoDB, the mongoose project offers schema definitions, amongst other things. With mongoose you can set up a `User` object definition (i.e. schema), and then make use of it like so:

```
var user = app.db.models.User.findOne( {...})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I thought that that may be the case.  The problem I have with this is that I am using MySQL.

Comment: @PobLivsig Ah OK. So do you have an existing schema defined in MySQL? Is there a `User` definition you can then work with, perhaps with an ORM tool like bookshelf? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077700/using-existing-mysql-schema-in-nodejs and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007353/which-orm-should-i-use-for-node-js-and-mysql

Comment: I had never heard of an ORM before.  Thank you very much.  I will take a look at the ORMs and take another look at how much time Mongo would take to learn and then make a decision.  Thank you again.  I have learnt a lot.