# Node.js options for MySQL ORM

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sequelize.js, waterline, node-orm2

I want to create a node.js and MySQL based application. Google and Stack Overflow give many options for Javascript ORMs:

- [sequelize.js](http://sequelizejs.com/)
- [persistence.js](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs/)
- [waterline](https://npmjs.org/package/waterline/)
- [knex.js](http://knexjs.org/)
- [node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/)
- [bookshelf.js](http://bookshelfjs.org/)
- [objection.js](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/)

However, I could not find an perfect ORM that supports subqueries, joins, transitions, stored procedures, is compatible with MySQL cluster, and has good documentation and community support.

Are there other options? What considerations should I take into account in making a decision?

Comment: Dont know if it fits all your needs, but https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql works really well.

Comment: node-myql is pkg for mysql connection i am searching orm when we can use association object

Comment: This questions should be marked as off topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7646459/1520671

Comment: It's been my experience that ORMs make initial development easy, but lead to unnecessary complexity and clumsy database structures later on. If you're working with mysql, use the node-mysql module (it's very very good) and deal with SQL. It's not so hard and much easier to scale and maintain down the line.

Comment: I think in this case I would prefer [sequelize.js](http://sequelizejs.com). Great documentation !

Comment: http://sailsjs.org is a great tool

Answer (score 2):

You should try [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/). It is a quite different, but still really easy to use. The best I like on it, is their auto synchonizer, which it is quite like Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

Use [light-orm](https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm) and [mysql](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql).
Light-orm is wrapper around any relational db and mysql is best mysql driver for node.

https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm

https://npmjs.org/package/mysql

Comment: You should let people know that you actually created light-orm.

Comment: Thanks to @FRD, stackoverflow is not a place to use it for commercial