# Is there a node object-relational mapping package?

Tags: sql, node.js

I come from a Java world where we have JPA && JPAQL to handle the object->relational mapping.  Is there something similar in node?  I'm not talking about a driver to issue SQL statements, but a true object layer library.

I found the [orm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/orm) package, but I want to make sure there isn't one that's essential become the standard-bearer (unless orm is it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is.

[Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/)

It looks pretty straight forward to use it:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  birthday: Sequelize.DATE
});

sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  return User.create({
    username: 'janedoe',
    birthday: new Date(1980, 6, 20)
  });
}).then(function(jane) {
  console.log(jane.get({
    plain: true
  }));
});
```

There is also this one: [Which ORM should I use for Node.js and MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007353/which-orm-should-i-use-for-node-js-and-mysql)